# Can I connect two monitors - one in docking station and one in laptop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, thinkpad, docking-station

I have two monitors and a THINKPAD USB-C DOCK GEN2 (image shown below).
[image: ThinkPad Docking Station]

You can see that the docking station has only one HDMI output. I have two monitors with DVI to HDMI cabels.
Is it at all possible to connect one monitor to the docking station and the other to the laptop's HDMI output? I have tried to close the laptop's screen , but it doesn't detect my second monitor (Windows 10). It detects only the one in the docking station.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar dock at home. Try connecting the dock first. Wait for the screen connected to the dock to activate. Then connect the other screen to your laptop. This worked for me, hope it works for you as well.

As an alternative, you could get an adapter for one of those free Displayport slots.

Comment: nope, I have tried every combination possible - still Windows can't detect the second monitor...